# Tween not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

i want to move an element on stage using the Tween class, so i did as usual:

```
import fl.transitions.*
import fl.transitions.easing.*
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.System;

new Tween(q1, 'x', Elastic.easeOut, q1.x, 600.5, 2, true);
```

it worked fine everytime i used it, but now i get these Error messages:
[image]

any ideas what might caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Classes of **fl** package are not built-in, they are an extension available in Flash IDE (CS3 and up) only. You are *most probably* using some other IDE or environment where **fl** classes are unavailable.

Comment: I'm using Flash Professional CC 2014, and the Tween works fine everytime, but sometimes (it's been the second time now in 3 months) i get this error.